# Probability of Inequality of Normally Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

**I have the problem below:**

> Let X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub> and Y<sub>1</sub> be independent random variables such that
>  X<sub>1</sub> ∈ N(3,2), X<sub>2</sub> ∈ N(3,2) and Y<sub>1</sub> ∈ N(12,√11). 
> What is P(4⋅X<sub>1</sub>+3⋅X<sub>2</sub> > Y<sub>1</sub>)?

I don't know how to solve this problem, the difficult part for me is that there are multiple random variables, I am not used to this. I am very thankful for any help.

Comment: Hint: $Z = 4X_1+3X_2=Y_1$ is a _normal_ random variable. Can you figure out the mean and variance of $Z$? If so, can you write down an expression for $P(Z > 0)$?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand, P(X1+3X2>Y1)  is the same as P(X1+3X2 - Y1 > 0) which is the same as P(Z > 0) where Z = X1+3X2 - Y1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any linear combination of independent normal random variables (RVs) is also a normal RV. You can prove it by deriving the characteristic function of their sum.

The new mean is sum of the means, the new variance is sum of the individual variances.

Now you know the mean and variance of $4X_1+3X_2-Y_1$, it's trivial from there.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that the new mean would be the sum of the means and the new variance would be the sum of the variances, thank you!

Comment: If you know about characteristic functions (CF), it's a really quick proof from there. For the means, you can actually just take the expectation and deduce that the new mean is the sum of means. Same for the variances are the covariance terms will be 0. You need the CF to prove you end up with a normal variable.